# User inputted TextField Array from Grid

Tags: swiftui

I have a grid view that has two columns, one that is static that will be populated with names, and the second that is user inputed numbers. I have two arrays, one full of the names, and one that is initialized to 0s for all numbers. I have it displayed as:

```
ScrollView{
            let lastRowIndex: Int = viewModel.names.count - 1
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                Group {
                    Text("Name")
                    Text("Number")
                }.font(.headline)
                ForEach((0...lastRowIndex), id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(viewModel.names[index])
                    TextField("indiv value", value: $viewModel.individualValues[index], format: .number)
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal)
        }
```

This displays perfectly to start, two columns, one with every name in the array and one initialized to 0. But when I try to make any change to the number, as soon as I click off of the input it returns to 0. How do I set this up so that the numbers are saved in the individualValues array, displayed properly, and able to be used later?

Edit: My updated code is:

```
struct NamesAndTimes: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var userId: String
  var fullName: String
  var indivValue: Double
}

class AddTimesViewModel: ObservableObject {
     var namesAndTimes: [NamesAndTimes]

     ...
     init (users: [User]) {
        self.namesAndTimes = users.map{u in
          return NamesAndTimes(
            userId: u.id,
            fullName: u.firstName+" "+u.lastName,
            indivValue: 0
        )
        }
     }
}


struct AddTimes: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: AddTimesViewModel 

    ...

    ScrollView{
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                Group {
                    Text("Name")
                    Text("Number")
                }.font(.headline)
                ForEach($viewModel.namesAndTimes) { $rT in
                    Text(rT.fullName)
                    TextField("type",
                              value: $rT.indivValue,
                              format: .number
                    )
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal)
        }
```

Which works logically, but currently does not update the view. Even when I change the value, it displays as 0. If I click back the typed in value displays, and is entered in Firebase if I click save, but I would like the view to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code could work, given you use something like: `@StateObject var viewModel = TheModel()`.

You would be better off using a more robust structure for your `names` and `individualValues`, than
the separate arrays, and accessing them through a common `index`, not a good idea and not recommended.

Here is my example code of that approach that works for me and achieve what you ask:
`How do I set this up so that the numbers are saved in the individualValues array, displayed properly, and able to be used later`

```
// -- here, name and value are tied together
struct ModelItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var value: Int
}

class TheModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [ModelItem] = [ModelItem(name: "item-1", value: 1),
                                         ModelItem(name: "item-2", value: 2),
                                         ModelItem(name: "item-3", value: 3)]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = TheModel() // <-- here
    
    var columns: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                Group {
                    Text("Name")
                    Text("Number")
                }.font(.headline)
                ForEach($viewModel.items) { $item in   // <-- use $, and not index
                    Text(item.name)
                    TextField("indiv value", value: $item.value, format: .number)  // <-- here
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to have gotten me at least part of the way there, so thank you for the help. With your approach, it initially shows the same table of names and 0 values. If I change a time from 0 and click away, it appears as 0 still, however if I click back then the value shows. What could be causing that 0 value to still show even though it knows it is a different value?

Comment: The code I show works well for me. 
Do you get this issue using my code or using your code. If using your code, then show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without this I can only guess at what you are doing in the code you don't show. Can you try just my code and let us know if this gives you problems.

Comment: I have updated my post with the minimal reproducible code, please let me know if you see any problems. Thanks for the help

Comment: use `@Published var namesAndTimes: [NamesAndTimes]` like I have in my example code. Show the code you use to pass `AddTimesViewModel` to `AddTimes`. Also show how/where you declare `@StateObject var viewModel = AddTimesViewModel()`  in your code and how you pass it to `AddTimesViewModel`?